# I want to compute square of 1000000.I am using java which data type should I use,I tried using primitive double and even Bigdecimal

Tags: java

I want to compute square of 1000000.I am using java which data type should I use,I tried using primitive double and even Big decimal... Is there any data type or class which I can Use??

Comment: [This Java tutorial page on Java data types and limits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) should help you decide which datatype to use.

Comment: `long` should be able to store that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 2):

1,000,000 * 1,000,000 is one trillion (1e12).

`long` can hold up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which is much larger than one trillion and so is suitable for your calculation.

'int' can hold up to 2,147,483,647 which is not large enough for your calculation, and so is not suitable.

`double` and `float` are floating point and do not seem necessary for your use case at this time (unless you are actually trying to take the square root?).

Comment: When i run following code                                           long d= 1000000*1000000;
System.out.println(d);                                                       I get Out put as:   -727379968                                         I Should get 1000000000000 right?

Comment: instead run `long d = 1000000L*1000000L`

Comment: @user1164369 blgt is right, to declare a `long` literal you need to add the `L` at the end, otherwise the JVM treats it as an `int` in the expression (until it is widened for the assignment).  So without the `L` the expression is calculated with `int` arithmetic and overflows before being cast to a long.